# Is there any dataset that contains eye class for YOLO?

Tags: python, detection, yolo

I'm looking for something that can help me with detection of eye via YOLO method. Is it even possible? Saw that COCO and pascal VOC datasets are wide but there's lack of eye class. Is there any dataset or something that could help me with such detection?

Comment: SO isn't really the proper forum for this type of question. Questions about software recommendations are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually train for custom classes. If you have GPU you can use or else use Google Colab.
Here is the link for tutorial

```
https://youtu.be/GRtgLlwxpc4
```